# Why can't I get a Singleton when I use return instance ?: synchronized(this) { instance ?: PreferenceParameterState(context) }?

Tags: kotlin

I think that both the Code A and Code B are equivalent, they will return Singleton by using following code.

```
preferenceParState: PreferenceParameterState = rememberPreferenceParameterState()
```

I use `preferenceParState.hashCode()` to test them, I find the Code B  can  return Singleton, but Code A can't return Singleton, why ?

BTW, `mContext.hashCode()` have the same value in different instance in Code A by my testing.

**Code A**

```
class PreferenceParameterState private constructor(context: Context) {

    companion object {     

       @Volatile private var instance: PreferenceParameterState? = null

        fun getInsance(context: Context): PreferenceParameterState{          
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: PreferenceParameterState(context)
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun rememberPreferenceParameterState(): PreferenceParameterState {
    val mContext= LocalContext.current
    return remember {
        PreferenceParameterState.getInsance(mContext)
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class PreferenceParameterState private constructor(context: Context) {
    companion object {
  
         @Volatile private var instance: PreferenceParameterState? = null
        fun getInsance(context: Context): PreferenceParameterState{
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = PreferenceParameterState(context)
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun rememberPreferenceParameterState(): PreferenceParameterState {
    val mContext= LocalContext.current
    return remember {
        PreferenceParameterState.getInsance(mContext)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have never assigned anything to `instance` in Code A, so `instance` is always `null`. BTW kotlin provides a [simple way to create singleton](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview)

Comment: Thanks! You can't apply  `constructor(context: Context)` for a Object declarations

Comment: But providing a parameter is fundamentally broken if you want singleton semantics. If you call `getInstance` twice with different contexts, you will get twice the same instance that was built with the first context, which feels wrong for the second call

Comment: @Joffrey Gotta love the Android Context.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I wish SO implemented reactions to comments :D

Comment: Probably worth highlighting the `@Volatile` here: without it, the [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) here wouldn't be thread-safe, and could create two instances, or even worse, return a partly-constructed instance. (Multi-threading is full of subtle gotcha…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your Code B does is create an instance based on the context that was passed the first time it was called. In all subsequent calls, the context parameter is ignored. If that is really what you want (unlikely), then you can make Code A do the same thing by changing one line:

```
        return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: PreferenceParameterState(context).also { instance = it }
        }
```

But if you want a singleton per context, you can use a ConcurrentMap:

```
class PreferenceParameterState private constructor(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        private val instances: ConcurrentMap<Context, PreferenceParameterState>
            = ConcurrentHashMap()

        fun getInsance(context: Context): PreferenceParameterState
            = instances.getOrPut(context) { PreferenceParameterState(context) }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention it being unlikely, but on Android it makes sense if you're using the Application class's Context. But it would be cleaner here to make the argument an Application, and then using `application.context` in the constructor call. There can only be one valid instance of Application, so this would ensure no ambiguity about passing different instances as an argument.